# Passing object in Electron IPC yields old object version

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, electron

I'm experiencing a behavior of Electron's IPC that seems weird. The setting is an app that, when clicking on a button, performs a download in the main process via IPC, like so (in renderer.js):

```
$('#Download').click(async function () {
  await app.download();
  updateUI();
}
```

The download function in main performs the download, then updates a main.js closure-scoped object named `items`, like so:

```
app.download = async function() {
  const response = await fetch('https://...');
  const result = await response.json();
  await result.items.forEach(async element => {
    items[element.id] = element.content;
  }
  console.log('Nr of items: ' + Object.keys(items).length);
}
```

After the download is complete, the UI should be updated. For this, there's a getter in main.js:

```
app.getItems = function() { return items; }
```

The renderer process uses it to update the UI:

```
function updateUI() {
  var items = app.getItems();
  console.log('Received items: ' + Object.keys(items).length);
}
```

However, given this flow, `app.getItems` always returns the `items` state *before* the download, i.e. missing the new items and showing a lower result for `Object.keys(items).length)`. Only after I refresh the Electron app window, it returns the state including the downloaded items. I tried several methods to get the updated item list back from main to renderer:

1. Have the `app.download` function return the items: Same result (!) - the item count written to the console differs between main and renderer. I even output timestamps on both sides to assure the renderer is called *after* main.
2. Trigger the UI update from main using `webContents.send('UpdateUI')` and calling `updateUI` in an `ipc.on('UpdateUI')` handler: same result.
3. Add `items` to `app.global` in main, and retrieve it via `remote.getGlobal()` in renderer: same result.

It was only the final try that succeeded:

4. Pass `items` as a parameter with `webContents.send('UpdateUI', items)`

Now before refactoring the code to use this pattern I'd really be curious if anyone can explain this :-)

The only idea I have is that passing variables between main and renderer is not "by reference" (given they're two isolated processes), and that Electron's IPC does some kind of caching when deciding when to actually copy data. I carefully added `await` on every reasonable place (and the timestamps indicated I succeeded), so I'd be surprised if it's caused by any async side effects.

Comment: I don't really understand. Your renderer is calling `app.getItems()`, but that function exists in the main process? There's no IPC happening here if that's the case. The renderer is just requiring its own version of `getItems` which won't return the updated items. Depending on what Electron version you're on, you'd do `await ipcRenderer.invoke("getItems")` and main would do: `ipcMain.handle("getItems", () => items)`

Comment: The renderer is requiring {app} from electron.remote. Based on the Electron docs, that what they say how to call functions in main, as far as I understand.